# How can i trigger job B after job A is already done in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two separate jobs A and B, i need to trigger job B as soon as job A is done.
im note quite sure how to configure job B to be triggered automatically knowing that each job has its own repo.

Comment: Which type of jobs do you use (freestyle, pipeline ...)? Does the job B depends on the build result (success, stable, failed) of the job A?

Comment: they are pipeline jobs both are on same jenkins server, but we want them to be seprate, 
if the JOB A done successfully i want to trigger JOB B automatically

Comment: Have you tried with **Build after other projects are built** under **Build Triggers** in job configuration?